# Check if database is running on production environment

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I have a Postgres database in the production environment for which I don't have access to. All I want to do is to check if the database is up and running, Is there any command or program or anything to check this? Just need to verify if it's up as easy as possible. **I know the password, the database, the host/servername and the database accountname**

How do I use all of these parameters to check if the database is up and running. The guys that configured the production environment have made so that no one outside the production environment can touch it. The production environment is Linux and iam using windows in my virtual desktop

Comment: The `pg_isready` command seems like it might be one good option here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-isready.html

Comment: seems like a good command, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a connection on the default port, which the Postgres service is running.

Some Administrators use default ports for database services:
Try checking 5432 or 5433 as the default ports.

Comment: Just because something is listening on port 5432 doesn't mean that that "something" is a Postgres server

Comment: That is correct, but you can try connecting remotelly or sending a request and then wait for the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Win and you're looking also for solution, then you may check some dedicated monitoring software like NetCrunch.